# How can I make the second value in a JavaScript YUP validation schema not required unless the first value is true? (ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have the following YUP validation written in JavaScript for ReactJs:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import helpers from '../../Shared/validationHelpers';

const { ipAddress, domainName, hostnameLinux, hostnameWindows } = helpers.regEx;

export function getValidationForPlatform(platform: string) {
    const nic = Yup.object().shape({
        useDHCP: Yup.boolean().notRequired(),
        ipConfig: Yup.object().shape({
            ipAddress: Yup.string().when('useDHCP', (useDHCP, schema) => {
                return useDHCP
                    ? schema
                          .nullable()
                          .matches(
                              ipAddress,
                              'Please use a valid IP address (ie: 127.0.0.1)'
                          )
                          .required(
                              'An IP address is required when not using DHCP'
                          )
                    : schema.notRequired();
            }),
            netmask: Yup.string().when('useDHCP', (useDHCP, schema) => {
                return useDHCP
                    ? schema
                          .nullable()
                          .matches(
                              ipAddress,
                              'Netmask should be a valid IP address (ie: 255.255.255.0)'
                          )
                          .required('Netmask is required when not using DHCP')
                    : schema.notRequired();
            }),
            gateway: Yup.string().when('useDHCP', (useDHCP, schema) => {
                return useDHCP
                    ? schema
                          .nullable()
                          .matches(ipAddress, {
                              message:
                                  'Gateway should be a valid IP address (ie: 10.1.1.1)',
                              excludeEmptyString: true,
                          })
                          .required('Gateway is required when not using DHCP')
                    : schema.notRequired();
            }),
            otherwise: Yup.object().notRequired(),
        }),
    });

    const ntpServer = Yup.string()
        .test(
            'IP or Domain',
            'Please enter either an IP address or a valid domain name',
            (value) => {
                const isIP = ipAddress.test(value);
                const isDomainName = domainName.test(value);

                return isIP || isDomainName;
            }
        )
        .notRequired();

    const hostNameLin = Yup.string()
        .max(15, "Hostname can't be longer than 15 characters")
        .matches(helpers.regEx.noWhitespace, "Hostname can't contain spaces")
        .matches(hostnameLinux, 'You must enter a valid hostname')
        .required('You must provide a hostname');

    const hostNameWin = Yup.string()
        .max(15, "Hostname can't be longer than 15 characters")
        .matches(helpers.regEx.noWhitespace, "Hostname can't contain spaces")
        .matches(hostnameWindows, 'You must enter a valid hostname')
        .required('You must provide a hostname');

    let hostName = hostNameWin; //default to windows in case something goes wrong, as windows is stricter
    if (platform === 'WINDOWS') {
        hostName = hostNameLin;
    }

    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
        nic: nic,
        ntpServer: ntpServer,
        hostName: hostName,
    });

    return schema;
}
```

The purpose of that function is to return a schema that changes based on data it gets from the backend, in this case whether the backend is a linux or windows machine. **However, I also need the second value of nic, ipConfig, to only be checked if the first value in nic, useDHCP is FALSE. Meaning that any data in ipConfig shouldn't even be checked if useDHCP isn't enabled.** How do I modify the code to do this? I'm not very familiar with YUP and when I wrote this, I was trying to just get it to work at all and not throw any errors.